# User Text in SQL Statement Cause App to Crash

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext

I have an edittext, a button and a sqlite table. When the button is pressed a select statement runs that includes the text that was entered. The app works fine if the user only enters numbers, but crashes if it contains letters.

Here is the schema of the table:

```
    public static abstract class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
    public static final String STOP = "entryid";
    public static final String LINE = "title";
    public static final String SCHEDULE = "schedule";
}
```

The table is initialized. The onClick method is:

```
public void lookUp(View v) {
        mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
    String string = mEdit.getText().toString();

    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] projection = {
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.STOP,
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.LINE,
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.SCHEDULE,
    };

    String sortOrder =
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.SCHEDULE + " ASC";

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            projection,
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.LINE+" = " + string ,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder
    );
```

Why does the app crashes when I have letters in the edittext? The columns are string types, so a string shouldn't crash it.

Here is the logcat error:

```
(1) no such column: line1
Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mycompany.antibes, PID: 2767
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: line1 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT entryid, title, schedule FROM entry WHERE title = line1 ORDER BY schedule ASC
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
    at com.mycompany.antibes.MainActivity.lookUp(MainActivity.java:61)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: yet anoter ... `SELECT blablabla, blabla, bla FROM BLABLA WHERE bla=bla` **is not a valid SQL statment** (and you just produced such query with your code) ... the most important part is `bla=bla`

Comment: @selvin thanks a lot

Comment: just use sql paramters ( `selection` + `selectionArgs` arguments of `SQLiteDatabase.query(..)` )...

Comment: don't understand your reply sorry

Comment: SQL's basics: how to use literals

Comment: I understand that the most important part is the sql request, this is ok. however showing the problem in the context of the request is more difficult since I am in android...

Comment: @MD where do I find the logcat, please?

Comment: 2 Things I would suggest: First, while developing you should add a log that is just your sql statement, so that you can make sure it's not some ridiculous thing causing all of this. Second: It's not the cause of this, but you should close your cursors and database whenever you're done querying to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: heh, should be `SELECT blablabla, blabla, bla FROM BLABLA WHERE bla=blavalue` is not a valid SQL statment if blavalue is a literal not a column name ...

Comment: please could you help me reformulating my question? I would like to contribute in a positive way to the website and for the moment I am blocked from ask questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql is

```
SELECT entryid, title, schedule FROM entry WHERE title = line1 ORDER BY schedule ASC
```

which means it's comparing title to a column instead of a value.

Try adding single quotes around your string.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(
        FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, 
        projection,
        FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.LINE+" = \'" + string + "\'" ,
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        sortOrder
);
```

So you would get

```
SELECT entryid, title, schedule FROM entry WHERE title = 'line1' ORDER BY schedule ASC
```

which seems to be what you're trying to do.

Comment: terrible idea ... `string = "boby'; DROP TABLE FeedEntry;--"`

Comment: @Selvin that idea worked...by contrary you adviced nothing constructive :)

Comment: @Selvin All he has to do is add code to check for a single quote then block that as input. His question was specifically about why his sql was failing.

Comment: @Helios83 Not a problem. I would suggest reading my comment on your original post to avoid situations like that again. And be sure to mark it as the accepted answer so you can help others that come across this question later!

Comment: @CodyHarness could you please post the request corresponding to your solution? just for understanding better my mistake. thanks if you can.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you're asking for.

Comment: @CodyHarness you said that my request is wrong because I am comparing wrong things. But how would it traslate your corrected request in the SQL language?

Comment: please could you help me reformulating my question? I would like to contribute in a positive way to the website and for the moment I am blocked from ask questions. Thanks.

Comment: @Helios83 I just submitted the edits for review, you'll hopefully see them shortly. Make sure you mark this answer as the correct one if it helped you solve your problem, that should also help your rating.